# Is there a way to covert MS Access reports and forms to any web application framework?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, web-applications, ms-access-2007

I am trying to migrate MS Access DB to SQL Server and looking for options to convert the reports and forms. As per my knowledge, Acess to SQL Server migration will only handle tables and data. How to migrate reports and forms? If someone try to build a webapp with this DB, how can they reuse the existing forms and reports?

Comment: Migrate the frontend to what? And why? Use Ms Access frontend with sql server backend and be happy!

Answer (score 2):

They can't.

It's a complete rewrite in any sense, indeed as SQL Server is the database only, supplemented by Reporting Services, but these reports are quite different from Access reports.

Answer (score 1):

You can no more re-use or convert some software that runs on your android phone to work on an apple phone, or run on your windows desktop, or run on the web for that matter.

You can no more put a DVD into a CD player and expect it to play you the movie.

So, software written to run on the Apple Mac will not run on windows. Nor will it run on android, and it will not run on the web as web based software.

And a AM radio can no more play FM radio then some software written in Access work on android, on an apple computer or in this case the web.

You can no more take the tires off your bicycle and expect those tires to work on a car or truck.

You can’t take the motor from your mixer and put that in a microwave oven and expect it to work.

So, if you ever used say something designed to work as a toaster? Well, that toaster can’t become a blender.

So, this is really a question about observation things in life and has VERY little to do with software. The only real concept that you need to grasp?

Well, software is a designed and engineered product. So, while both a Ford and a Chevy truck have a speedometer? You can’t simple take one from the Ford Truck and put that same speedometer into the Chevy truck.

Software is not any different than say a toaster. It is an engineered and designed product that does what it was designed to do.

So, be it swapping a speedometer or something like a simple gas gauge from a Ford Truck to the Chevy truck? Not practical.

Software is the same. You can no more take the software that runs in your alarm clock and then have that software work or run to display the time on the dash of your truck.

And the same goes for software. Software built and designed for the desktop can no more be run on the web then trying to move that Ford gas gauges to the Chevy truck. They have different designs and architecture – and thus are different products.

But many different tools all can consume electricity. And electricity is quite much the same concept for software. So, excel or sql server can both consume data, and so can a coffee maker and a power drill (consume electricity). So consuming electricity, or in this case data is what software consumes.

But, the fact that a power drill and a microwave BOTH consume electricity? That don’t suggest, hint, or even by the most simple logic and reason suggest that you can use your microwave oven as a power drill because both the drill and microwave consume electricity.

So, software can consume data – but like products consuming electricity?  That does not mean or even suggest that one product can be used for another purpose.

Desktop software and web software? It is the same difference between a power drill and a microwave – they are different products – you can’t in a practical sense use one designed product for another purpose. You can try to use your microwave as a hammer, but it just not all practical.

So, you if can grasp this concept of different things have different use?

Then the ONLY requirement here is that you have the ability to distinguish between say something designed as a toaster vs that of a microwave oven. If you can grasp the difference between a microwave and a toaster? Then you have the required knowledge to grasp why your desktop software can’t work on the web.

So, no, you can no more convert that software to run on the web then you can use a toaster in place of a microwave.

Different products are different products – they tend to not by magic morph into something else. This applies to software or a toaster.